# El servidor solo recibe peticiones GET al conectar desde android con HttpsUrlConnection, aunque fuerce la conexion POST

Tags: android, android-studio

Antes de nada saludar a la comunidad en general, soy nuevo en esta plataforma.
He visto varios hilos relacionados, en este y otros foros, con el problema que me esta reventando los sesos: **El servidor (API RESTFul en PHP) solo recibe peticiones GET usando el HttpsUrlConnection de Android*.

La API responde bien en cuanto a al tipo de peticiones, he probado con varios clientes (restlet client, insomnia, etc) y funciona, pero con la app android el servidor siempre recibe GET y actua en consecuencia. Este es el fragmento de código que uso, el cual he reducido al mínimo para testear y forzar el POST:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://direccion");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.getOutputStream();
        OutputStream output = conn.getOutputStream();
        output.write(conn.getResponseCode());
```

Depurando la APP he observado que el objeto de la conexión HTTPS tiene el parámetro Method="Get" y setDoOutput=false y nunca cambian, aunque el objeto delegate httpUrlConnection si que tiene el valor POST y True para setDoOutPut.   Pantallazo del Debug:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene idea de que puede estar pasando, o si hay alguna forma de  implementar una solución (he intentado extender httpsURLconnection para sobrescribir setRequestMethod,pero ha sido mas lioso). 
Gracias y Un saludo.

Comment: con.setRequestMethod("POST");

Comment: Gracias por responder Bryro, pero como comento esos métodos los aplico pero por lo visto modifican el objeto delegate (HttpUrlConnection), no el principal (HttpsUrlConnection).

Comment: Sin el código que utilizas es muy dificil saber cuál es la razón por la que no funciona lo que intentas hacer

Comment: Llevas razón Jorgeys,  he intentado explicarlo lo mejor posible, cuando llevas tanto tiempo dándole vueltas a algo ves tan clara la situación que al explicarla faltan matices. La verdad es que estoy probando código muy simple para testear este problema. Básicamente  saber si  a alguien le ha pasado o debo seguir depurando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por agregar más información @JoséGinésGiménez he revisado tu pregunta y sabes con respecto a esto "El servidor solo recibe peticiones GET" es precisamente porque esta configurado de esta manera, si tu tratas de enviar una petición "POST" no funcionará a menos que esta sea permitida, comenta a quien administra esa url que configure pueda recibir peticiones "POST".

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys, pero el servidor responde bien a los diferentes métodos usando otros clientes. Voy a desarrollar una pequeño código en eclipse ver como se comporta  desde ahí. Gracias.

Comment: Al parecer es un tema de  certificados. Sin entrar mucho en detalle porque aun tampoco lo tengo claro, el código que usaba para validar el sll (uso un certificado autofirmado para desarrollo) permitía la conexión y conectaba sin problemas, sin embargo usando, para testear, un código que acepta cualquier certificado (sin comprobar autoridad ni nada) funciona.